# I am unable to ping two machines each other despite they are on same domain network

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtual-machines, ping, active-directory

I am having two VM's equipped with 180 trial versions of Windows server 2008 R2 SP1. In one i have configured active directory domain services and ran dcpromo.exe on it and added the other server to the domain with this.

I am unable to ping two machines each other despite they are on same domain network. What might be the reason. Will the Microsoft patch updates to be done.

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Do the local firewalls on the machines allow pings?

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to ping before running dcpromo? Most likely you need to allow icmp through the Windows Firewall.

Here's a MS article on how to do that:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc972926(v=ws.10).aspx